# Can views be added within GridView cells?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create the following screen in my android app:

[image]

Except I may need to list up to 9 or more teams.  I've been looking at GridView, but I can't find anything in the [GridView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) or [ListAdapter docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) to show that I can do that.  Is this possible or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible or am I looking in the wrong place?

It is possible with `GridView`, `View`, `BaseAdapter` and `LayoutInflater`. You can inflate the views of the cell (each cell is the `View` here). For example:

`main.xml`:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    <!-- add additional properties as needed --!>
</GridView>
```

`player.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_team_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/teamName"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
       <!-- add or modify the properties as needed --!>
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`ImageAdapter.java`

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private final String[] teamValues;

        public LayoutInflater inflater;
        public LinearLayout ll;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] teamValues) {
            this.context = context;
            this.teamValues = teamValues;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View gridView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                gridView = new View(context);

                // get layout from player.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player, null);

                // set value into textview
                ll = (LinearLayout)gridView.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_team_name);
                textView.setText(teamValues[position]);

                String team = teamValues[position];
                // add team members here
                //
                //
                //                    

            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }
    }
```

`GridViewActivity.java`

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

    GridView gridView;
    ImageAdapter mImageAdapter;

    String[] teamName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        teamName = getTeamName();
        mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, teamName);

        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        registerForContextMenu(gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu iMenu, View iView, ContextMenuInfo iMenuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(iMenu, iView, iMenuInfo);

        iMenu.setHeaderTitle("TEAM NAME");
        iMenu.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < nTotalTeam; i++) {
            iMenu.add(Menu.NONE, i, Menu.NONE, teamName[i]);
        }
    }

    private void getTeamName() {
    //
    // getTeamName and return the array of string
    //
    //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A GridView is absolutely right here.  Each view in a GridView is a View-  whatever view you want.  And yes, you can programatically add new views to it.  THe different cells don't even need to be the same type of View if you don't want them to be-  its all very flexible.